# Golang net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: go, http, ssl

I'm trying to parse `https://****.ru/`. On my local machine in docker container I get no errors, but when I try to start my parser in docker container on the server, I get `Get "https://***.ru/" net/http: TLS handshake timeout.` error.

```golang
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: 20 * time.Second,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
            CipherSuites: []uint16{
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305, // Go 1.8 only
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,   // Go 1.8 only
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            },
        },
    },
}

rq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", link, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

res, err := client.Do(rq)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I tried to set `InsecureSkipVerify` to `true`, tried to extend handshake timeout, but it didn't work.
Although curl on the server works fine.

Comment: I don't think your error is related to TLS configuration but to DNS resolution on the server side. Are you able to ping the address on the server side?

Comment: Why are you specifying all the ciphers? Try removing you `TLSClientConfig` and using the default.